# Find patient ID at least appears two time and more

Tags: r

```
df<-data.frame(PATIENT_ID=c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,5,5))
```

I want to find the patient ID which has been recorded for at least 2 times.

The output should be:

```
df_output<-data.frame(PATIENT_ID=c(1,3,5))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another dplyr solution, using `summarize` instead of a combination of `mutate` then `filter`. First, we group by the variable, we count how many observations per group, then keep only when there are two or more observations. The last step keeps only the variable of interest (removes the new `n` column)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>%
    summarize(n = n()) %>%
    filter(n >= 2) %>%
    select(PATIENT_ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another `dplyr` solution

```r
df %>%
  group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>%
  filter(n() > 1 & row_number() == 1)
```

And `data.table`. (I'd prefer to use `.SD`-logic here, but [data.table#3262](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3262) is still open, and your sample data does not have other columns. It's not much faster, though this would be different if the data were significantly larger.)

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[, .(n=.N),by=PATIENT_ID][n>1,][,n:=NULL][]
#    PATIENT_ID
# 1:          1
# 2:          3
# 3:          5
```

If your data is any larger than the sample, these benchmarks will change but likely in the same ratio: user31264's answer will almost certainly be the fastest still, and the more-complicated `dplyr` pipes will likely retain their relative performance.

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  user = {
    a = rle(df$PATIENT_ID)
    data.frame(PATIENT_ID=a$values[a$lengths>1])
  },
  user_sort = {
    a = rle(sort(df$PATIENT_ID))
    data.frame(PATIENT_ID=a$values[a$lengths>1])
  },
  r2a = df %>%
    group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>%
    filter(n() > 1 & row_number() == 1) %>%
    ungroup(),
  r2b = DT[, .(n=.N),by=PATIENT_ID][n>1,][,n:=NULL],
  csg = df %>%
    group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>%
    summarize(n = n()) %>%
    filter(n >= 2) %>%
    select(PATIENT_ID),
  duck = df %>%
  group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>%
    mutate(N=n()) %>%
    filter(N>=2) %>%
    select(-N) %>%
    filter(!duplicated(PATIENT_ID))
)
# Unit: microseconds
#       expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
#       user  116.2  138.55  168.536  167.30  180.30   366.2   100
#  user_sort  160.1  184.55  238.249  224.60  255.60   464.3   100
#        r2a 3018.4 3399.60 4020.076 3839.70 4202.95 12193.5   100
#        r2b 2094.6 2945.30 3367.188 3277.80 3838.35  5183.8   100
#        csg 5382.5 6262.20 6708.582 6670.90 6992.80  9078.2   100
#       duck 7538.3 8568.55 9275.720 8928.65 9420.20 16678.5   100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = rle(df$PATIENT_ID)
df_output=data.frame(PATIENT_ID=a$val[a$len>1])
```

If df is unsorted, the first line should be `a = rle(sort(df$PATIEND_ID))`

Comment: While this gives the desired output, two things (perhaps that explains a downvote?): (1) partial-match on property names might produce warnings for some users (minor); and (2) typo in `PATIEND`. I think this is the simplest (and base-R at that).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>% mutate(N=n()) %>%
  filter(N>=2) %>% select(-N) %>% filter(!duplicated(PATIENT_ID))

# A tibble: 3 x 1
# Groups:   PATIENT_ID [3]
  PATIENT_ID
       <dbl>
1          1
2          3
3          5
```

Comment: If you `tally()` instead of mutate, you won't have to `filter(!dup...`, as it auto-reduces. You can simplify it further with `df %>% group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>% filter(n() > 1 & row_number() == 1)`.

Comment: @r2evans Yeah it is a pretty optimal way to do that!